# parsing a 360-day calendar in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, calendar

I need to read in a csv file that contains dates in the 360-day calendar format, each month having 30 days! Is there a way to tell pandas that it is okay to have a 30 day february? It always throws "day out of range for month" error!

I tried normal to_datetime function which didn't work.

Edit: I have to handle a few different calendar types, so it would be ideal to just allow pandas to make exceptions, and not just specify somehow the 360-day calendar as the only type.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please add the `input csv file` and the `expected output`. So that it will be easier to understand

Comment: I don't think you could do that with datetime format since it would break any other date-related operation like telling which day of the week is 30 February. Obviously you can read those as plain strings, so the real question is how to achieve whatever you are planning to do next with those dates.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite not possible, as the python pandas expects dates to be in the `standard Gregorian calendar` format, that is each month having a specific number of days.

I don't think it has a built in option to handle a 30 day February.

But there is a function in `pandas` - `pd.DateOffset(days=30)`. You can explore this.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with the standard datetime format. Simply because there are no 30 days in february.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832672/pandas-excel-days360-equivalent), looks similar.